# Entity-relationship model

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-relationship

I am creating a simple entity-relationship model. Here I have one or more animals that can get one or more services. [image: ER-model] 
My question is which attributes's the connection type "get" going to have. I was thinking that it will get the unique attributes of animals and svervice that is "animal-ID" and "service-ID", and that will be foreign keys in "get".

Comment: Correct.  Next question please.

Comment: Will this also be primary key in get? @MikeNakis

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Okay, so "get" will have one Animal-ID (PK), one Animal-ID (FK), Service-ID (PK), one Service-ID (FK)) @MikeNakis

Comment: How will the information that I have in "get" go to the other tables? If I for example have a entity " employee" connect to service, how will this entity get the information from get?

Comment: Your question was `which attributes's the connection type "get" going to have.`  Stackoverflow is not a place where you can learn programming by having discussions with people.  Discussions are actually discouraged.  If you want, you can create a new question.  But still, you cannot learn elementary things by asking questions.  It would be a much better use of your time (and our time) to read a book.

Comment: And no, "get will not have all that which you list in your previous comment.  "get" will only have one Animal-ID and one Service-ID.  Both of these will form the primary key.  Also, Animal-ID will be a foreign key to Animal(Animal-ID), and Service-ID will be a foreign key to Service(Service-ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical many-to-many relationship looks like table with two columns referencing two entities. In your case it's (actual syntax depends on dbms):

```
CREATE TABLE Get (
  animal_id INT NOT NULL,
  service_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY animal_id REFERENCES animal (animal_id),
  FOREIGN KEY service_id REFERENCES service (service_id)
)
```

Sometimes it makes sense to extend linking table by some link properties. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE Get (
  animal_id INT NOT NULL,
  service_id INT NOT NULL,
  service_paid BOOLEAN,
  provided_date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY animal_id REFERENCES animal (animal_id),
  FOREIGN KEY service_id REFERENCES service (service_id)
)
```

But in general it's just two foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

This will be used to link the tables that were originally related in an M:N relationship